# Why these statements need different time to run in R?

Tags: r

code as follow:

```
a<-function(){
  for(i in 1:1000000)
    w1<-w1+2
  w1
}

b<-function(){
  for(i in 1:1000000)
    w1[1]<-w1[1]+2
  w1
}

c<-function(){
  for(i in 1:1000000)
    w1[1]=w1[1]+2
  w1
}

w1<-1
system.time(a()) #0.39
system.time(b()) #1.78
system.time(c()) #1.89
```

the only difference is :

```
w1<-w1+2
w1[1]<-w1[1]+2
w1[1]=w1[1]+2
```

they spend different time to get result,maximum is almost four times of minimum.

**so I want to know what causes this difference?** .

It seems difference between `=` and `<-` is slightly in speed.But there is a huge difference between `w1<-w1+2` and `w1[1]<-w1[1]+2`.

Comment: Indexed assignment require more operations. There's no compiler optimization at play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is overhead.

The function `a` is simply adding two numbers together and storing the result in memory.

The functions `b` and `c` are retrieving values from a vector and storing the result in the vector. The reading to and writing from the vector causes additional overhead which takes additional time.

Comment: so is function **a** better when write a code which is used for computing?